# How to disable uitextField.rightView's editing feature.

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

so i have implemented a uitextfield in my app and set its right view to be a button to trigger something.

However, whenever i pressed the rightView of the uitextfield, it also triggers app to start editing (keyboard shows up).

How do i disable the editing when the rightView of the uitextField is pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: simply inside of right button action write this line [self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom subclass:

```
@IBDesignable class TJTextField: UITextField {

    fileprivate var ImgIcon: UIImageView?

    @IBInspectable var errorEntry: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var leftTextPedding: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var lineColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var placeHolerColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 199.0/255.0, green: 199.0/255.0, blue: 205.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var errorColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var imageWidth: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var txtImage : UIImage? {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return self.newBounds(bounds)
    }
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return self.newBounds(bounds)
    }

    fileprivate func newBounds(_ bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        var newBounds = bounds
        newBounds.origin.x += CGFloat(leftTextPedding) + CGFloat(imageWidth)
        return newBounds
    }

    var errorMessage: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        //setting left image
        if (txtImage != nil)
        {
            let btnLeft = UIButton()

            btnLeft.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(imageWidth), height: self.frame.height)
            btnLeft.setImage(txtImage, for: .normal)
            self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
            self.leftView = btnLeft
            btnLeft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TJTextField.btnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
    func btnClicked()
    {
        if !self.isEditing
        {
            self.resignFirstResponder()
        }

    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let height = self.bounds.height

        // get the current drawing context
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // set the line color and width
        if errorEntry {
            context?.setStrokeColor(errorColor.cgColor)
            context?.setLineWidth(1.5)
        } else {
            context?.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)
            context?.setLineWidth(0.5)
        }

        // start a new Path
        context?.beginPath()

        context!.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: height - 0.5))
        context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: height - 0.5))
        // close and stroke (draw) it
        context?.closePath()
        context?.strokePath()

        //Setting custom placeholder color
        if let strPlaceHolder: String = self.placeholder
        {
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:strPlaceHolder,
                attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:placeHolerColor])
        }
    }
    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
    {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(imageWidth), height: self.frame.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: why do we need to put IBDEsignable and IBInspectable here ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Its a subclass of UIButton, IBDEsignable and IBInspectable will render live on storybord.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Just set TJTextfield as super class of your button and all your work done.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you add your button view after you add text field to your superview. In that case it will overlap text field and intercept tap gestures.

Or you may simply set constraints to specific width or to left button side.